# Sublime text causing the print() statement to print brackets and quotation marks

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3

for most of my programming as a beginner I have been using a site called grok learning. On this website, there is a python interpreter(?) I'm not sure what the technical word is, but you can basically run python programs with some modules inside the site.

Today I downloaded sublime text because the space on Grok Learning was not as large as I needed, and I couldn't save the programs to my computer.

I copy and pasted some of my code from Grok to sublime text, and for some reason, I am having this problem.

On grok, this program:

```
world_age = random.randint(2, 5000)

print('The world is', world_age, 'years old.')
```

returns this:

```
The world is 2500 years old.
```

However, in sublime text, I get:

```
('The world is', 3068, 'years old.')
```

With brackets and all. I am using python 3, not 2, so I know the brackets have to be there. Other notes:

- I am using mac OSX
- To run the program, I downloaded python 3.6.3 from python.org for mac
- I am saving the sublime text file in .py form in my own folder, and to run it I right click the file and choose open with Python Launcher. If I choose to open with "IDLE" then the program doesn't actually run, the program just opens in python.

Comment: Sublime text is running your code in Python 2. Or rather, whatever *Python Launcher* is; are you right-clicking in *Sublime* or in *Finder*?

Comment: Ah, I see the OS X installer includes a `PythonLauncher` app, and it is configurable: *PythonLauncher has various preferences to control how your script is launched. Option-dragging allows you to change these for one invocation, or use its Preferences menu to change things globally.*. Presumably it is currently configured to run Python 2.7 by default.

Comment: Try opening the Python Launcher app (located in your `Applications` folder and looking at its preference pane. It probably has an option to set what Python binary is used.

Comment: Thank you Martijin, I thought if it was running in python 2 that my program designed for python 3 wouldn't work at all, but I guess they aren't so different.

Comment: Sorry I hit enter meaning to go down a line, but can you please explain what "option-dragging" is? The options available for me are "Settings for file type" which is currently set to "Python script" with the other options being "Pyhton GUI script" and "Python ByteCode Document" as well as "other flags" and "command line" with a bunch of things I don't understand.

Comment: You'd only need to set the `interpreter` option for the Python Script file type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not Sublime's fault. You are running your Python script with the Python Launcher, and it is configured to run Python 2. Your code happens to work under Python 2, but the `print` statement is given a tuple to print.

Open the Python Launcher directly ([use Spotlight to find it](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/ht204014)) and you can adjust the Python binary it uses to run your script. When you launch it the preferences pane will open automatically. You can set the `interpreter` option to the path of the Python 3 interpreter instead.